# Syntax error, node.js with the following "Object.keys(colors).forEach((code) => "

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm learning node.js, one of my node modules (irc-colors) will keep returning this error every time I run `npm start`

`missing ) after argument list", source: D:\Documents\Twitch-Chat-Bot-master\node
_modules\irc-colors\lib\irc-colors.js (44)`

Code in question

```
// Style functions.
Object.keys(styles).forEach((style) => {
  var code = styles[style];
  exports[style] = str => code + str + code;
});
```

It will work if I change it to

```
// Style functions.
Object.keys(styles).forEach(function(style) {
  ...
});
```

Now I don't think the way they've done the callback is a mistake since it's done like this multiple places, I think maybe this project is using the wrong version of JS? I'm unsure, I've never syntax like this before.

Someone please educate me, thank you

Comment: What ancient node.js version are you using?

Comment: `node --version` — first number should not be 0

Comment: Version v6.11.2

Comment: @Pointy I upgraded to v.8.94 and it still does not work. What could be going on here?